# Working days between two dates

Tags: sql, days, calculation

Is there a built in SQL function that will calculate working days between two dates?  Or is the below custom function the only solution?  Seems odd there doesn't appear to be one!  I imagine this is used often.

```
SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @fromdate, @todate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @fromdate, @todate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @fromdate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @todate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  As NoOfWeekDays
```

Comment: The definition of "Working Days" differs from business to business, and can even have multiple definitions within a single organization; corporate staff might work M-F, but a satellite office might add Saturdays, and the warehouse runs 7 days a week. There are also holidays to consider, which aren't "business days" but don't occur every week, and again those differ greatly from one organization to another. Ultimately any "working days" calculation is going to be fairly specific to its use case.

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  Makes sense but I thought a function similar to NETWORKDAYS in Excel might exist in SQL!